# How would I get the line with the highest (child?) value in JSON? (python)

Tags: python, json

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "coins": 10000003,
            "id": 580040383883378710
        },
        {
            "coins": 3,
            "id": 457775659998248960
        },
        {
            "coins": 101,
            "id": 630506515484377099
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I display, in this case, the id with the highest "coin" value (which in this casse would be 580040383883378710)?

Comment: What is the issue? Why can;t you iterate over using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json

json_data = '''{
    "people": [
        {
            "coins": 10000003,
            "id": 580040383883378710
        },
        {
            "coins": 3,
            "id": 457775659998248960
        },
        {
            "coins": 101,
            "id": 630506515484377099
        }
    ]
}'''

data = json.loads(json_data)
res = max(data['people'], key=lambda x: x['coins'])
print(res)
#{'coins': 10000003, 'id': 580040383883378710}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a place I could go to understand lanbda functions more?